# Creating Persistent p2p Groups in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, persistence, p2p

I would like to form persistent group so that after a disconnection, when previously disconnected device sends connection invitation GO doesn't need to accept the invitation. Here's an example, which will explain my problem better: I have nodes sta-1, sta-2, and sta-3. sta-1 creates group, then sta-2 and sta-3 send connection invitation to sta-1 with the line

`p2p_connect <sta-1 MAC address> pbc persistent join`

Then, sta-1 accepts the connection invitation using

`wps_pbc any`

Group formation is complete now. Then, I disconnect sta-1 tearing the group down. After this point, when either sta-1 or sta-2 (or both) send connection invitation to sta-1 with the same command above, I expect connection to happen automatically without the need of any confirmation, because I had created a consisted group. However, connection doesn't take place if I do not use `wps_pbc any` again.

At this point, my question is: how can I realize persistent connection without need of confirmation for connection invitation?

Answer (score 0):

In readme of the wpa_supplicant u can get something like

```
set persistent_reconnect <0/1>

Disable/enabled persistent reconnect for reinvocation of persistent
groups. If enabled, invitations to reinvoke a persistent group will be
accepted without separate authorization (e.g., user interaction).
```